# jquery doesnt select the child element of an selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make for users possible to select first 2 rounds or 4 rounds, then according to 2/4 round there is an input type text field where they have to write the number of tickets, then according to the selected event it jquery calculates the number of tickets and the price of the car and writes them into a div with a variable selected_event (*each div for the price has its own id with the name of the div*) `$('#' + selected_event).html("€ " + totale + ",00");`
The jquery code I wrote doesn't! maybe I could select the input field that is in the same parent div as the input type radio and then according to that input type text to change the price .cange() but I have problem selecting it, I tried with .child() .. parent()..

HTML:

```
<div class="more_car_info">
                <div class="small_car_image">
                    <img src="http://www.domain/slide1.jpg" style="width:101px;height:66px;">
            </div>
            <div class="car_ticket_anzahl_und_prise">
                <p style="float:left;"><span style="margin-right:45px;"><input value="2runden" alt="1" name="anzahl_ticket" type="radio" style="width: 20px !important;margin:0;height:25px;"> 2 Runden </span><span style="margin-right:45px;">199,00€</span> Anzahl Ticket: <input type="text" class="anzahl_tickets" name="Nürburgring" style="width:20px !important;margin-bottom: 4px !important;"></p> 
                <p style="float:left;"><span style="margin-right:45px;"><input value="4runden" alt="2" name="anzahl_ticket" type="radio" style="width: 20px !important;margin:0;height:25px;"> 4 Runden </span><span style="margin-right:45px;">359,00€</span> Anzahl Ticket: <input type="text" class="anzahl_tickets" name="Nürburgring" style="width:20px !important;margin-bottom: 4px !important;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    if($('input[name=anzahl_ticket]:checked').val() == '2runden' ) {
    $('.anzahl_tickets').change(function() {
            var selected_event = $('.anzahl_tickets').attr("name");     
            var nr1 = $('.anzahl_tickets').val();
            var nr2 = +nr1;
            var car = 199;
            var totale = (nr2 * car);
            alert(selected_event);
            $('#' + selected_event).html("€ " + totale + ",00"); //gesamtpreis
        });
}
else if($('input[name=anzahl_ticket]:checked').val() == '4runden'){
    $('.anzahl_tickets').change(function() {
        var selected_event = $('.anzahl_tickets').attr("name");
        var nr1 = $('.anzahl_tickets').val();
        var nr2 = +nr1;
        var car = 366;
        var totale = (nr2 * car);
        $('#' + selected_event).html("€ " + totale + ",00"); //gesamtpreis
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping out your `$('.anszhl_tickets)` selectors with `$(this)` inside your handlers like:

```
    var selected_event = $(this).attr("name");
    var nr1 = $(this).val();
```

If you have multiple elements on your page with the class `.anszhl_tickets`, your code won't do what you think since `$('.anszhl_tickets')` will match multiple elements.

Comment: I also have multiply elements with the class: anzahl_ticket for the radio buttons and for the input type text multiply elements with class: anzahl_tickets

Comment: the HTML above is repeated multiply times, the only thing that is different is the name of the inupt type field text: name="Nürburgring" is for this event, for other events is different..

Comment: I made a fiddle that does what you want for the most part I think... [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3zN9/3/)